# How to select multiple inputs with same name in jQuery and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to update the quantity record inside a MySQL DB with Ajax and jQuery. The problem is that I have an multiple input named `qty`, and jQuery is only triggering the onchange event when there are multiple times this input.

Here is a bit of JS code.

```
$('input[name^="qty"]').change(function(){
                var nqty = $('input[name="qty"]').val();
                var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                
                // sending ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax/update_devis_content",   // sending ajax request to this url
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                         'id' : id, 
                         'qty': nqty
                    },

                    // before ajax request
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        
                    },  

                    // on success response
                    success:function(response) {
                        alert("La quantité a été modifiée");
                    },

                    // error response
                    error:function(e) {
                        alert("Une erreur est survenue");
                    }

                });
            });
```

And here the HTML table

```
<table id="example-input" class="table table-bordered text-nowrap">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Nom</th>
                                                        <th>Quantité</th>
                                                        <th>PU TTC</th>
                                                        <th>PU HT</th>
                                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="tbody">
                                                    <?php foreach($devis_content as $d){
                                                    $pr = $this->Generate_model->get_product($d['produit']); ?>
                                                    <tr id="<?php echo $d['id']; ?>">
                                                        <td><?php echo $pr['nom']; ?></td>
                                                        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="number" name="qty" value="<?php echo $d['qty']; ?>" onchange="jsfunction()"></td>
                                                        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="prix_ttc" value="<?php echo $d['prix_ttc']; ?>"></td>
                                                        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="prix_ht" value="<?php echo $d['prix_ht']; ?>"></td>
                                                        <td><button class="btn btn-danger my-2 btn-icon-text remove" type="button"><i class="fe fe-trash mr-2"></i> Supprimer</button></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

I left the on change because I tried getting the closest element `tr` with that but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, instead of `$('input[name="qty"]').val()` use `$(this).val()`.Working code check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7f2c3ukj/) see console for results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it's surely better, but if I have multiple rows, it doesn't work with the first one, only the two others.. And if I have only one row, it doesn't work at all

Comment: not work with first one ? please elaborate .

Comment: rows are generated through  a foreach loop. When there is one row: the code isn’t working. It’s not detecting any change neither sending an error. When I have three rows, the first one of the list isn’t triggering the function $('input[name^="qty"]').change(function()

Comment: that code should work fine . are you sure there are no error inside browser console  and your input name starts with qty ?

Comment: I have no specific errors, and my input name is qty. So found a trick that seems to work: I created a hidden row so now it's working well. Strange error, and unconventional solution